# $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] returning wrong domain on Magento after URL change

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I have recently changed the site URL from the development domain to the new domain.

Having done this through the MYSQL queries the website loads perfectly fine on the new domain (I have edited my hosts file to trick this).

However when I echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] I seem to be getting the old domain.

Any one have an idea why this may be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: have you changed the name in the nginx config?

Answer (score 0):

This was a server configuration issue, simply changing the virtual host file to remove the wrong domain solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the var folder or flush the cache then it return the correct url.